ParallelMap only parallelize on first level
I have a 8 cores CPU.
The ParallelMap work well in first level.
LaunchKernels[]
ParallelMap[Labeled[Framed[#], $KernelID] &, Range[10]]

gives

However, when I am trying to parallelize the calculation in second level
ParallelMap[Labeled[Framed[#], $KernelID] &, {Range[10]},{2}]

It gives unexcept result:

all the elements are calculated in kernel 1. I have tried all the method (including CoarsestGrained, EvaluationsPerKernel,ItemsPerEvaluation,FinestGrained), but gives same results. Even for
ParallelMap[Labeled[Framed[#], $KernelID] &, {Range[10000]},{2}]

All the elements are also calculated in kernel 1. Actully, ParallelMap[f, {list},{2}] always use single core; ParallelMap[f, {list1,list2},{2}] always use double cores.
Is there any way to distribute the task to each kernel?

I don't know the reason why your code is processed in a single kernel.
Just as a workaround, use Map on ParallelMap:
list = {Range[10]}

(* {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}} *)

ParallelMap[Labeled[Framed[#], $KernelID] &, #] & /@ list


